# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.finsky.api.model.DfeToc.isGplusSignupEnabled()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, automated-tests

I'm publishing a new version of my app and use Google's test lab. Now I got a problem for the 1st time, evoked at a passage of code which I didn't change compared with all previous versions (which run perfectly):

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.me.myapp") );
if ( intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null )
    startActivity( intent );
```

Only on an Galaxy S6 with Android 5.1 (out of 12 devices) I get the following error:

*Problem: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.finsky.api.model.DfeToc.isGplusSignupEnabled()' on a null object reference:*

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.android.vending, PID: 20993 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   com.google.android.finsky.api.model.DfeToc.isGplusSignupEnabled()' on
>   a null object reference   at
>   com.google.android.finsky.detailspage.RateReviewModule.bindModule(RateReviewModule.java:94)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.detailspage.DetailsFragment2.rebindViews(DetailsFragment2.java:476)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.activities.DetailsDataBasedFragment.rebindViews(DetailsDataBasedFragment.java:138)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.fragments.PageFragment.onDataChanged(PageFragment.java:261)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.activities.DetailsDataBasedFragment.onDataChanged(DetailsDataBasedFragment.java:263)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.api.model.DfeModel.notifyDataSetChanged(DfeModel.java:100)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.api.model.DfeDetails.onResponse(DfeDetails.java:91)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.api.model.DfeDetails.onResponse(DfeDetails.java:16)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.api.DfeRequest.deliverResponse(DfeRequest.java:569)
>     at
>   com.google.android.finsky.api.DfeRequest.deliverResponse(DfeRequest.java:56)
>     at
>   com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)      at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

I have no idea if I'm able to crash the Google Play app but that's the screenshot Google's test lab provided. Can anybody give me a clue what I did wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried exactly your snippet (of course exchanging my app identification):

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.me.myapp") );
if ( intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null )
    startActivity( intent );
```

And indeed, it seems that one of these test devices in Google's test lab crashes the moment it should simply launch the Google Play app.

So, my answer is: I confirm that this NullPointerException has nothing to do with the tested app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, during the last 4 weeks this error remained with each and every revision I uploaded (about 8). So, I can't believe that Google wouldn't fix it if this error is really only related to one of their devices. Finally, I still fear that one thing in my app is at least part of the problem.

Comment: OK, let's see if there's any other people around with the same problem.

Comment: Same problem for the first time today, but I'm not using that piece of code. It's curious that even if it crashes, the device is not reported as problematic in the graph at the top